# OleDbCommand.ExecuteReader Throwing Exception

Tags: c#, exception, .net-3.5, oledbconnection

My C# .NET 3.5 application is throwing an unusual exception when executing `OleDbCommand.ExecuteReader`.  The application makes 5 similar queries of an Access 2007 database.  Three of the queries execute without any problems; the other 2 cause exactly the same exception to be thrown.

This is a query that passes:

```
String query =
    "SELECT " +
        "bas.[BAS BACnet Object Type/Instance], " + // OBJECT_IDENTIFIER_ATTRIBUTE/ITEM_REFERENCE_ATTRIBUTE
        "bas.[BAS BACnet Object Name], " +          // USER_NAME_ATTRIBUTE
        "bas.[BAS Point List Description], " +      // DESCRIPTION_ATTRIBUTE
        "bas.[BAS Monitor Only], " +                // MONITOR_ONLY_ATTRIBUTE
        "ref.[ENUM_H], " +                          // PROPERTY_REFERENCE_VALUE_ATTRIBUTE
        "yk.[CCC Max Value (eng units)], " +        // MAX_PRESENT_VALUE_ATTRIBUTE
        "yk.[CCC Min Value (eng units)], " +        // MIN_PRESENT_VALUE_ATTRIBUTE
        "yk.[CCC Enum/Data Set], " +                // UNITS_ATTRIBUTE
        "ore.[ORE COV Increment], " +               // COV_INCREMENT_ATTRIBUTE
        "ore.[ORE Display Precision] " +            // DISPLAY_PRECISION_ATTRIBUTE
    "FROM (([OV2 BAS] AS bas " +
    "INNER JOIN [OV2 ORE] AS ore ON bas.[Ref ID] = ore.[Ref ID]) " +
    "INNER JOIN [OV2 RefID] AS ref ON bas.[Ref ID] = ref.[Ref ID]) " +
    "INNER JOIN [YK CAPP] AS yk ON bas.[Ref ID] = yk.[Ref ID] " +
    "WHERE bas.[BAS BACnet Object Type/Instance] LIKE 'AV%';";

this.RunQuery(query, MappingTable.AV_QUERY_IP_FIELDS, this.IPAnalogValuesList);
```

This is a query that throws throws an exception:

```
String query =
    "SELECT " +
        "bas.[BAS BACnet Object Type/Instance], " + // OBJECT_IDENTIFIER_ATTRIBUTE/ITEM_REFERENCE_ATTRIBUTE
        "bas.[BAS BACnet Object Name], " +          // USER_NAME_ATTRIBUTE
        "bas.[BAS Point List Description], " +      // DESCRIPTION_ATTRIBUTE
        "bas.[BAS Monitor Only], " +                // MONITOR_ONLY_ATTRIBUTE
        "ref.[ENUM_H], " +                          // PROPERTY_REFERENCE_VALUE_ATTRIBUTE
        "ses.[ENUM_H], " +                          // STATES_TEXT_ATTRIBUTE
        "ore.[ORE States] " +                       // ACTIVE_TEXT_ATTRIBUTE/INACTIVE_TEXT_ATTRIBUTE
    "FROM (([OV2 BAS] AS bas " +
    "INNER JOIN [OV2 RefID] AS ref ON bas.[Ref ID] = ref.[Ref ID]) " +
    "INNER JOIN [OV2 ORE] AS ore ON bas.[Ref ID] = ore.[Ref ID]) " +
    "INNER JOIN [StatesEnumSet] AS ses ON ore.[ORE States] = ses.[ID] " +
    "WHERE bas.[BAS BACnet Object Type/Instance] LIKE 'BV%';";

this.RunQuery(query, MappingTable.BV_QUERY_FIELDS, this.BinaryValuesList);
```

Here is how all of the queries are executed:

```
private void RunQuery(String query, Int32 fieldCount, Object target)
{
    OleDbCommand cmd = null;
    OleDbDataReader reader = null;

    try
    {
        OleDbConnectionStringBuilder connection = new OleDbConnectionStringBuilder();
        connection.Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0";
        connection.DataSource = XML_Generator.Program.MappingTableFilename;
        connection.PersistSecurityInfo = false;

        this.DbConnection = new OleDbConnection(connection.ToString());
        this.DbConnection.Open();

        using (cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, this.DbConnection))
        {
            cmd.Connection = this.DbConnection;
            cmd.CommandText = query;
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(); // <== Exception is thrown here.

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                . . .
            }
        }

        if (this.DbConnection != null)
        {
            this.DbConnection.Close();
            this.DbConnection = null;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }
}
```

This is the exception:

> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: No value given for one or more required parame
>   ters.
>      at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextErrorHandling(OleDbHResul
>   t hr)
>      at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextForSingleResult(tagDBPARA
>   MS dbParams, Object& executeResult)
>      at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandText(Object& executeResult)
>      at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommand(CommandBehavior behavior, Ob
>   ject& executeResult)
>      at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReaderInternal(CommandBehavior behav
>   ior, String method)
>      at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
>      at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReader()
>      at XML_Generator.MappingTable.RunQuery(String query, Int32 fieldCount, Object
>    target) in C:\ccmdb\prep\ov2_shared_cec_v1.0\ov2_shared_cec\Private\Tools\XML_G
>   enerator\XML_Generator\MappingTable.cs:line 312

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: question..where are you declaring the reader object..?

Comment: @DJKRAZE: It's declared locally in the function.  I've updated the OP to clarify.

Comment: ok I didn't see that..ok let me look at your code again there is a better way to create the OleDbCommand and connection objects give me a second also can you post what the full connection string is.. the way it's declared in your code it's hard to tell if there may or may not be an issue there.. are you using a .config file at all.? I would recommend placing the connection string in the  config file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone renamed one of the fields in the database. -_-

Answer (score 1):

here is an example of what a OleDbConnection, Command and DataReader object can be declared
example of how the Connection String should look if you choose to make this a static variable

```
<add key="strAccessConnectionString" value="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\castonmr\Documents\"Your AccessDB Name.mdb";Mode='Share Exclusive';Jet OLEDB:Database Password="your password";"/>    


try
{
    OleDbConnection oleconn = null;
    OleDbDataReader reader = null;
    oleconn = new OleDbConnection(strAccessConnectionString);
    oleconn.Open();
    using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand())
    {
       cmd.Connection = oleconn;
       cmd.CommandText = query;
       cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
       reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    }
}//try
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: Should I close the database, after the `using` statement completes?

Comment: depends on what you want to do.. the using will Dispose of the underlying connection and return it to the connection pool.. it depends on what you truly need to do.. repeated opening and closing of connections could be costly in regards to round trips

Comment: Thanks.  Does `reader.Read()` need to be inside the `using` block as well?

Comment: From your example, it looks like `cmd.Connection` is set to `null`.  Is that correct?  Should it be set to `oleconnStkLink`?

Comment: no necessarily but if you plan on doing any reading from that within a while loop why not just keep it within the using.. it will not hurt it since the null assignment of the reader was declared outside the using() this makes it still accessible I normally do my coding within the using

Comment: @Jim he still needs to update his code to point to a valid oleConn I believe that I stated that in the portion where I was suggestion he add the connection string to the .config file

Comment: If the oleConn was invalid, wouldn't all 5 queries fail?

Answer (score 0):

this error could be because your mdb doesnot have all the columns/object required  to run query, you may double check mdb file and see if the query run there properly

Comment: I have double-checked the database.  All this started happening when I updated the queries to reflect a change in the database (a new column was added to one of the tables).  This new field (BAS Monitor Only) is referenced the same way in all of the queries.

Comment: maybe do some trial and error, change error query to select bas.*, * to analyse the column return,